# How to launch an activity after clicking a widget?

Tags: android, view, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

I want to create a simple widget with an icon to launch my app.

I have the widget and its layout working properly, but I can't find the way to make it launcher the app when clicking it.

This is the widget class:

```
public class LauncherWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Attach the intent to the widget's button.
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

I have never created a widget so I have no idea what to do here.
I have checked round here for more info but all I can find are widgets that update its content when clicking, but I tried to use their code but it isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me...

The onUpdate method code should be:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                        "Activity.class"));
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context, 0, intent, 0);
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                        R.layout.widget_layout);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        "There was a problem loading the application: ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code and it is working partially. I am able to register the click event on the widget but am unable to launch the activity. I used your code with some minor modifications to suit my class names etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet in onUpdate() method of your widget AppWidgetProvider class:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);

    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, configPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't launching the activity I want to.